# Node Getting error using new with ES6 class stored in variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, subclass

I have the following master ES6 class that holds references to other ES6 classes that are dynamically called later in my code like so:

```
class Root {
   constructor() {
       this.refs = {
         ref1: require('ref1')
         ref2: require('ref2') 
       }
   }
}

module.exports = exports = new Root;
```

ref1 and ref2 export new instance of the `class Ref1` and `class Ref2`.

Later down the line, I attempt to make an instance of one of these references classes by doing:

```
const Root = require('root');

class other {

 someFunc() {

   var ref = new Root.refs['ref1'](value);
 }

}
```

This always ends with the following error:
`TypeError: this.actions[action.action] is not a constructor`

How can I properly make a reference to these ref classes?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new Root()`?

Comment: If I correct the syntax errors then it parses and runs well. The error message you copied here clearly does not come from this code. We are more than happy to help, but please submit an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `()` after `new Root`.

If the export is set with default you might also want to try with `require('ref1').default`

Comment: what is the advantages/disadvantages using adding the ```()``` and using ```the.defaults``` method?

Comment: `()` ìs a must if you want to initialize the `new` class. It is the way you initialize the constructor. `default` is required for gathering the `export default`. If you are using `module.exports = Class` it is not. It all depends if you are using ES6 or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are not exporting the class `Root` you are exporting an instance of class Root by using the `new` keyword.

Change it to say `module.exports = Root;`